# In Tensorflow, is there a direct way to construct an array tensor from a scalar tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

For example, something similar to:

```
x = 12
y = np.array([[x, x], [0, 0]])
```

Is there a direct to construct the array tensor y given scalar tensor x in Tensorflow? Without using tf.expand_dims and tf.pad.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
y = ?
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: When I try to run `y = np.array([x, x], [0, 0])` I get a `TypeError`. Can you clarify what behavior you'd like to see?

Comment: It should be y = np.array([[x, x], [0, 0]]), sorry. The original post is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`tf.convert_to_tensor()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor) function to do this:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)  # NOTE: You should probably pass `shape=[]` as well.
y = tf.convert_to_tensor([[x, x], [0, 0]])
```

Also note that TensorFlow will implicitly call `tf.convert_to_tensor()` on the inputs to any function that expects a `tf.Tensor` as input, so you may be able to pass `[[x, x], [0, 0]]` directly to many functions.